# Connecting with CEO or management on Linkedin

Tags: management, linkedin

I recently started working at a company and was considering connecting with my higher level management that I work and interact with on a weekly basis.

In my case they would definitely recognize and remember me as I take a fairly important role in the company.

Would it seem normal to try to connect or could this be seen as something negative?

Comment: If you interact that frequently, why not just casually ask "Would you like me to connect to you on LinkedIn?".

Comment: As someone who works in IT my social skills are not the best and I would personally find it to be an awkward question (Not saying all IT people are bad at social interactions). But yes, that is one option. Thank you.

Comment: Next time you talk you could ask Are you on LinkedIn? and then when they say yes, just mention that you are too and might send them a connect invite. Make it nonchalant. Wait a few days before actually sending the invite.

Comment: @Brandin - If your comment were an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: Pro-tip: your social skills are never going to get any better if you keep hiding behind the "I'm in IT" excuse

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Would it seem normal to try to connect or could this be seen as
>   something negative?

Although you can never know how others will perceive it, wanting to connect with co-workers via LinkedIn is completely normal.

Sometimes others limit their connections, so it's possible your request won't be accepted, but I'd be surprised in the CEO or upper management were offended in any way.

And as @JoelEtherton correctly points out, their mere presence on LinkedIn suggests that they want to build their network and they want people to request connections.

Comment: To supplement, I would say their mere presence on LinkedIn suggests that they want to build their network and they want people to request connections.

Comment: Completely agree with this. Adding them to Facebook or another personal level social network could be strange.... But the entire point of LinkedIn is to be a professional network for colleagues and business contacts